# PRIMARY filegroup is full

Tags: sql-server

Since there is no space left on my SQL server, I keep getting the following error and I have to delete data to get the system working again.

The hosting company says we do not have unlimited package options. They suggest that we switch to the server. Apart from that, I saw the 'shrink' on the internet, but will this damage the database or will it be the definitive solution for me?

> Could not allocate space for object in database because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Comment: Shrinking won't help; SQL Server will use any free space in the files first before it grows them. If you don't have enough storage space for your data there really are only 2 choices: *1. Get more storage. 2. Delete uneeded data.* Perhaps it's time to relook at your data retention policy.

Comment: Compression may help also, especially on large tables which are not heavily used

Comment: Change your recovery model? But first, you need to consult your disaster recovery plan and make sure 1) you have one and 2) it is documented, tested periodically, and well known to multiple persons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, Shrink Database won't help you because SQL Server will use all free space in the file before it attempts to grow it.

So your options are as follows:

**Archive or delete old data**

If you have audit tables, large blobs that no longer need to be accessed, or other data that doesn't need to be accessed within your application any more, you can SELECT it out of the database, store it in a file somewhere as an archive (or retrieve it from an older backup when you need it).

**Apply table compression**

If you are running Enterprise SQL, or a version of Standard/Express/Web after 2016 SP1, you can apply [Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/enable-compression-on-a-table-or-index?view=sql-server-ver15) to larger tables. This converts CHAR columns to be physically stored as VARCHAR columns, among other things, and I have seen it gain 1/3 space back on some SQL databases. However, you will run into the problem of needing space initially to perform the compression in, so you may need to apply this in concert with #1. A restart of the database service may also give you some space back from tempdb in which to operate if your tempdb has filled.

**Upgrade storage space**

If your host can't meet your storage space needs and #1 and #2 are not possible, it may be time to look at changing hosts. This may be a good idea anyway as your database will no doubt eventually grow back to bigger than its current size.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that if you have microsoft sql express server the license limits you to about 10 GB per database so you cannot increase the primary group more than that. For Sql Express Server before 2008 the size limit is even less.